# SourceMap header is ignored on different host

Tags: javascript, google-chrome, source-maps

If I'm serving bundle.js from http://localhost:5000 with the SourceMap: /bundle.js.map it works fine, however when I include `<script src="http://localhost:5000/bundle.js"></script>` on http://localhost:5001 (serving the files as before), the browser (Chrome 71) won't load the source map. Is this a bug in the browser or something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes it does not work in Chrome. The solution is to include the source map not via the header but via the `//# sourceMappingURL=<url>.map`.

Comment: Why doesn't it work? There is any source indicating that? It's supposed to be supported and works fine on Firefox